Ajax heavy GET operation stops routing on website
I am working on making an older website more responsive.
The site is working with some complex data relations and when there is a lot of data to be loaded it can take 10s of seconds to just show some of the pages.
First initiative I have done is making the backend processes asynchronous so I can load in elements as they are ready instead of waiting for the whole bunch to be ready. In that process I have changed some of the partialViews on the frontend to generate most of their DOM after the page has loaded.
<script>
    $(window).on('load', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action(controllerUrl)',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('Received data:', data);
            if (xx.success && xx.yy.length > 0) {
                var html = '';
                <!-- more dom generation-->
                
        error: function(){ generating some error relevant div }

My problem is that even these smaller parts of the page requires some heavy data handling on the backend. And while one of these ajax requests waits on a response the website can't route to another page on the site, when the user clicks a button to navigate away from the page that is loading an element. As soon as the ajax GET for any element the routing seems to fire but as some of these GET requests can still take upwards to 5 seconds I would like a way to cancel the waiting of the request and just navigate somewhere else.
Note: It's not the dom generation that takes time as soon as the data is returned to the frontend its done near instant.
Note: Almost all of the backend is still running synchronous, so it might just be a case of some synchronous process having to wait for something else.
I used the $(window).on('load', function ()) instead of the document.ready which helped such that the UI thread is free to navigate to another page when one element is loaded.

Instead of creating HTML on the client side, manipulate and create HTML over the server and directly load that HTML via Ajax in one go.

Also, add a loader over the page so that until the content is loaded fully user cannot click anywhere

Its not creating the HTML that takes time its the get request in the Ajax and then the data handling on the backend. I don't see how creating the html server side would make a difference then. The Ajax is still going to be waiting for the data response either way. Adding a loader on the page is exactly what I am moving away from since it had users sitting waiting for a page to load for ages.

handling data over the server side is always faster than creating and updating over the client side. for example creating a table of 2000 records over server will take too less time than asking data from server and then creating table by using jquery/javascript code.
